# how to use apostrophe ( ' inside " and then inside ' )

Tags: php, scripting, apostrophe

I need to issue this command via sudo in php. But sudo needs to have the command inside apostrophes.

```
psql -c "create database radek with encoding 'unicode';" -U edumate template1
```

so

```
sudo -su postgres 'psql -c "create database radek with encoding ''unicode'';" -U edumate template1'
```

gives me an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "unicode"
LINE 1: create database radek with encoding unicode;
                                            ^
```

I'd say that the error happens because unicode is enclosed by '. And sudo command is enclosed by ' too.

## UPDATE

escaping unicode `\'unicode\'` doesn't work. I get `>` and it hangs there for ever....

## UPDATE2

the final php code is like

```
exec("sudo -su postgres 'psql -c \"create database " . $db . " with encoding '\"'\"'unicode'\"'\"';\" -U edumate template1'", $output);
```

thanks to @Matthew Scharley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit weird, but what's happening with your double apostrophe is that it's closing the string then reopening it again, which gains you a net of nothing. The solution is the following:

```
sudo -su postgres 'psql -c "create database radek with encoding '"'"'unicode'"'"';" -U edumate template1'
```

ie. Put the apostrophe in double quotes between the close and open. This will work in at least `bash` type shells, but I don't use others to know how they work.

Comment: one more think... I call sudo from php ... and `exec("sudo -su postgres 'psql -c \"create database " . $db . " with encoding '"'"'unicode'"'"';\" -U edumate template1'", $output);` doesn't work. The above works from command line not from php.

Comment: @Radek: Welcome to quoting hell; we hope you enjoy your stay. You need to escape **all** the double quotes: `exec("sudo -su postgres 'psql -c \"create database " . $db . " with encoding '\"'\"'unicode'\"'\"';\" -U edumate template1'", $output);`

Comment: noooooow my php script works. It restores postgres db ... thank you. PS It wasn't any hell for me because of you ...